# how to have the journal name shown when I cite a paper in beamer?

Tags: beamer, bibliographies

I am writing a `beamer` presentation and I would like citations to appear (in the text!) like "Doe et al., Journal of Latex Greatness, 2007". Instead if I use only the `\cite{}` command (together with `apalike` bibliography style). I only get the author and date [Doe et al., 2007]. Do you have any ideas? I use a large `bibtex` file that stores all the relevant information.

Comment: There are certain decisions made by the `beamer` author mostly concerning the simplicity and this is another one. In a presentation at most you need a name and a year and every slide, ideally, should be designed individually for the maximum clarity. What you are suggesting is against that view and also I think it's going to be ugly. However you can use other `.bst` styles for example http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43179/use-different-bibliography-styles-for-the-same-bibtex-database

Comment: thx! lets say I do not care whether it is ugly or not ;-) do you have in mind what I should change in the bst file in order to obtain this ? many thanks!

Comment: If you use the `natbib` citation management package, you could use its `\citetext` command to include nearly arbitrary amounts and types of text in the citation. Incidentally, even though you say that you don't care whether or not the material in a slide is ugly, I would still venture to guess that you do care to make your presentation effective. Unless you happen to have two or more citations by "Doe et al" published in a given year, I can't think of a single good reason for providing the journal name of the publication in the citation -- especially not if it's for a beamer presentation.

Answer (score 2):

This is easy to obtain with `biblatex`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[style=authoryear, natbib=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{test.bib}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
Two nice articles are  
\citetitle{ZINC} \citep{ZINC}  and  
\citetitle{Jorgensen} by \citeauthor{Jorgensen} 
in \citeyear {Jorgensen}.  
\end{frame} 
\begin{frame}
\printbibliography
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The file `test.bib` is:

```
@article{ZINC,
author = {Irwin, John J and Shoichet, Brian K},
title = {{ZINC--a free database of commercially available compounds for virtual screening.}},
journal = {Journal of Chemical Information and Modeling},
year = {2005},
volume = {45},
number = {1},
pages = {177--182},
}

@article{Jorgensen,
author = {Jorgensen, WL},
title = {{The many roles of computation in drug discovery}},
journal = {Science},
year = {2004},
volume = {303},
number = {5665},
pages = {1813--1818},
}
```

(References obtained from [Cite bibliography in beamer with a concrete style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26959/cite-bibliography-in-beamer-with-a-concrete-style))

[image: MWE]

Comment: Dear downvoter, can you explain why the downvote?